# SCORM Report generation storing whole options of multichoice in moodle

Tags: database, moodle, scorm, scorm2004

I have a question regarding SCORM report generation.

I have tried to load some SCORM 2004 packages in moodle and I saw tracks in database that stores questions and learner_response.

But my question is can we implement functionality of storing each option of multi choice questions like articulate shows in it features.(http://www.articulate.com/products/ao-features.php - See individual answers section in which whole options are being displayed.).

I am aware that only interactions get recorded in db. Can SCORM supports feature of storing whole options of multichoice questions?

Comment: Sorry for being late, i am using 2.2.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

How are you launching your SCORM 2004 courses in Moodel? Are you using the SCORM Cloud Moodle mod to play your SCORM 2004 courses in Moodle? If so, you can find the data that you're looking for in the Reportage section of SCORM Cloud in the "All Interactions" report. More information on the Moodle Mod is located [here](http://scorm.com/moodle/).

Comment: I am not using scorm cloud. I am using the basic functionality provided by moodle itself.